# Multimaterial in threejs issue

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have to apply obj files with texture, and i need to merge my new texture into existing obj. I was used following code

```
var materialArray = [];
 materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
   map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('admin/assets/overcoat/shadows/Coat_2_3_Lapel_Shd.png'),
   transparent: true,
   opacity: 1,
   polygonOffset: false
 }));
 var mesh1 = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry, materialArray);
 mesh1.scale = new THREE.Vector3(6, 6, 6);
 mesh1.position.y -= 2.5;
 SceneService.scene.add(mesh1);
```

But my got white line merge the textures. [image]

Any one help me to hide the line.

Comment: Here is my demo url https://fit4bond.net/fiddle/viewer.html . Check the code and what mistake i did? .

Comment: http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Edge_padding

Comment: try to add  mesh1.position.z = -0.1;